# "error CS0648: 'XYZ' is a type not supported by the language" exception on ALL types

Tags: c#, asp.net, runtime-error

I'm getting the above error on my website project whenever I attach to my w3wp.exe process, on ALL types. I cannot view the value of anything, not even a string. I'm not sure what has changed, but I've tried the following:

- Clean & Rebuild of website
- Clean of ASP.NET Temporary Files
- Clean checkout of project
- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
- Reinstall of Visual Studio Community 2015

Can anybody help me troubleshoot this?

Comment: @bash.d I see you added XYZ in place of the quotes. It specifically doesn't reference the type, and it was just two single quotes in the exception. Dunno if that's important in troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: @bash.d Well on it's own it's a bit of a pointless edit. You should know by now that you should tidy up the entire post (such as removing "Thanks!" from the end)

Comment: The two quotes looked like a double quote, which made the question look ill-formed...

Comment: from Microsoft - this error means: 'type' is a type not supported by the language
Metadata that was generated from another language, possibly C++, contained a type that was not marked as managed. Information about this type is included in the metadata, but the type is not available to programs written in C#. /end --> Did you added something, maybe some external dll?

Comment: No references were changed. I can't even peek the value of a string in the watch panel. I'm reverting windows updates now one by one...

Comment: No luck with rolling back windows updates. I moved to another pc for now, but my laptop is still having this issue.