# Can't see values while debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, and when I hit a breakpoint, I cannot get any info on the values of variables.

- When hovering over a variable, nothing comes up.
- In Immediate Window or Watches, I get:

  ```
  error CS0648: '' is a type not supported by the language
  ```

This happened all of a sudden, as it used to work until yesterday.

I've tried a few things including resetting all user settings, deleting *.user files, restarting Visual Studio, and even restarting Windows.

What else can I try?

Update: I've written a [blog post](http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/nasty-const-bug-in-asp-net-5/) about this problem and how to reproduce it.

Comment: '' sounds like a strange type. What type does the variable really have? Are all types affected?

Comment: There seem to be more issues like that lately. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32339956/error-cs0648-xyz-is-a-type-not-supported-by-the-language-exception-on-all-t

Comment: It gives me that for any type, even a simple `string`.

Comment: You may have somehow messed up project references and caused VS to load not your project files, but assemblies of some other version.

Comment: @Gigi Are you building your project in release or debug mode? If you are building in release then I wouldn't be surprised that the `const` is getting optimized away entirely, thus the "local" declaration of it is gone.

Comment: @vcsjones I think it was debug mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug currently being tracked by [aspnet/Home issue #955](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/955#issuecomment-144613912).

Console Application repro for reference:

**REPRO**

1. Open VS2015 (Windows 10, ASP.NET 5 Beta 7)
2. Click File > New > Project > Web > Console Application (Package) > Ok
3. Edit `Program.cs` to reflect code snippet below.
4. Add a breakkpoint just after `Console.WriteLine(a);`
5. Run the project
6. Right-click variables `a` and `b` click Add Watch

**CODE**

```
public void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int a = 3;
    int b = 4;
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

**EXPECTED**

Watch window displays values for variables `a` and `b`

**ACTUAL**

Watch window *Value* column for variables `a` and `b` displays:

> error CS0648: '' is a type not supported by the language

**NOTES**

1. The value of `a` is written correctly to Console
2. Removing `const` from the snippet reverts to EXPECTED bevahiour

Answer (score 10):

You won't believe this but it seems that this is somehow related to a `const` expression I had. Removing `const` and using a variable solved the problem.

How weird. Didn't manage to reproduce on a simple console application. The problem originally occurred on an ASP .NET 5 Web Application.

Update: see more details in my [blog post](http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/nasty-const-bug-in-asp-net-5/) which also explains how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I can verify. This just happened to me as well. In an ascx page (user control) in my c# mvc app, i had a const defined and got this error. Once i updated to a var, it works again. #VisualStudioBug!!!

Comment: I can verify too. It seems in addition that it is limited to the method where the const was declared. While inside that method, the Locals window will be empty and adding Watches will result in CS0648. Stepping out of the method will instantly show Locals again and Watches will also show values again. Havings class-level consts doesn't negatively affect the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I had one variable that had CONST and once I removed that all my types showed up and had values in them.